# Jolt Specification

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following input format

**INPUT.JSON**

```
[
    {
        "name": "adam",
        "age": 12,
        "address": {
            "city": "delhi",
            "country": "india",
            "zip": "110011"
        }
    },

    {
        "name": "louis",
        "age": 23,
        "address": {
            "city": "goa",
            "country": "india",
            "zip": "110022"
        }
    }
]
```

After applying jolt transformation i want to get the following output

**DESIRED OUTPUT.JSON**

```
[
    {
        "name": "adam",
        "age": 12,
        "address": {
            "current_city": "delhi",            //change here
            "current_country": "india",         //change here
            "zipode": "110011"                  //change here
        }
    },

    {
        "name": "louis",
        "age": 23,
        "address": {
            "current_city": "goa",              //change here
            "current_country": "india",         //change here
            "zipode": "110022"                  //change here
        }
    }
]
```

Can you please help me with the jolt spec.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "name": "[&1].name",
        "age": "[&1].age",
        "address": {
          // Shifting inside address object
          "city": "[&2].address.current_city",
          "country": "[&2].address.current_country",
          "zip": "[&2].address.zipode"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```